# Delphi ShellExecute not working in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, shellexecute

I just KNOW this is something simple, but I've tried all of the suggestions I could find on this forum, and I still can't get the following ShellExecute statements, which worked perfectly well for four years on XP, to work in Windows 7.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('command.com'), PChar('/c ftp -s:c:\checkout\WebFTPParams.txt 91.208.99.4'), Nil, SW_SHOW);
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('command.com'), PChar('/c ftp -s:c:\checkout\WWFTPParams.txt 212.78.232.39'), Nil, SW_SHOW);
```

---

Thanks anyway, folks, but I found the problem.  I should have been using CMD.EXE rather than good old Command.com.   Sorry for bothering you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command.com is not anymore in Windows (it was used in DOS). Use cmd.exe

Answer (score 2):

Different versions of Windows use different command-line interpreters.  Older versions use **command.com**, newer versions use **cmd.exe** instead.  Use `GetEnvironmentVariable('COMSPEC')` to discover the correct interpreter to use.

With that said, you don't need to use any interpreter in this situation.  **ftp.exe** is its own app, so you can just run it directly.  Although you can use `ShellExecute()` to run exe files, it really is not meant for that.  It will just delegate to `CreateProcess()`, so you really should cut out the middle man and use `CreateProcess()` directly instead.

Even better, rather than use an external process, you should consider using the FTP protocol directly in your own code.  There are plenty of third-party components, like Indy, ICS, Synapse, etc, and APIs, like WinInet, libcurl, etc, that have FTP client implementations, and are easily usable in Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, command.com is the DOS/Windows 9x command interpretor. But I see no reason to invoke a command interpretor at all. I'd do it like this:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'ftp.exe', '-s:c:\checkout\WWFTPParams.txt 212.78.232.39', nil, SW_SHOW);
```

There's no need to specify a verb here either.

Comment: Thanks David - it's cookbook stuff for me, I'm afraid.  I don't know much about the area, so I found a pattern which worked and followed it out the window!