# Delphi. ShellExecute command performs properly on Win 7 but not Win 8

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I am programming using Delphi 2010 on a 32-bit Windows 7 PC.

The following code works when run on my PC as admin.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ShellApi;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  { Private declarations }
  public
  { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShellExecute(0,'open','command','/c ipconfig /all > testipco.txt','',0);
  showmessage('Test IP Config file should be written');
end;

end.
```

The file TESTIPCO.TXT is output and contains the same results as typing ipconfig /all into a Command Prompt window.

When I compile the file and run it on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 PC as admin, the program appears to run OK, displaying the message (with no errors) but the file TESTIPCO.TXT is not produced.

Even running the exe on a Windows 8 machine with compatibility set to run as Windows 7 doesn't work.

I just cannot work out why this is the case. I'm hoping that one of you bright people may be able to steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Apologies. For clarification. It should say 'When I compile the program and run it on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 PC as admin' instead of 'When I compile the file and run it on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 PC as admin'.

Comment: See [Delphi ShellExecute not working in Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14170998/576719).

Comment: The command interpreter is `cmd.exe`. `command` is from DOS and Win 9x. You would be better using CreateProcess to start a process. But in any case ShellExecute doesn't report errors properly. Not that you appear to check for errors. You state that the program doesn't show any errors but of course not - you did not check for errors. Anyway, when you decide to add error checking you'll want to use ShellExecuteEx for its better error reporting. Still, CreateProcess is the right function here.

Comment: Are you sure `testipco.txt` file isn't created? Perhaps it is created but in a different folder. Since you are not providing the absolute file location for output file the file should be created in current folder of the command prompt which is not necessarily the same as the current folder of your application.

Comment: Thanks David. I realise that the points you make are very valid but I was trying to create an easy example of the error. When I develop the program I will of course use your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks SilverWarior. The file definitely wasn't being created. I had also tried providing the output file location.

Comment: It's no surprise that this program doesn't display any errors. You haven't written the code to display any. You're ignoring the return value from the API function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `cmd.exe` instead? `Command` is a somewhat archaic reference.